# Unity2D　アニメーターコントロールで一つのステートから複数の遷移を作成できない

Tags: unity2d

Unity2Dのバージョン　2020.3.32f1 Personal

アニメーターコントーロールでステートから遷移を1つしか作成できず困っています。
遷移を1つ作成すると、それ以降、ステートを右クリックしても、「遷移を作成する」メニューが出てきません。
（添付した画像Aの状態です。）
参考文献では一つのステートから複数の遷移を作成しているのです。
一つのステートから複数の遷移を作成する方法を教えてください。
[image: 画像A：遷移を作成できない]
画像A

参考：1つ目遷移を作成する際のメニュー画像
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
Editorのバージョンを2020.3.33f1にあげたところ作成できました。